# Integrate python code with php in apache web server without using exec command

Tags: php, python, apache, web-services

I have modules written in python. And I am running my webserver through php apache server. For invoking the existing python scripts, I'm using the following command and this works fine,

```
shell_exec("python.exe file.py args");
```

Is there a proper way apart fro doing **shell_exec / exec** comnand from php.

Comment: did u try chmod +x file.py?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that.

- Integrate Python into PHP. PHP supports C extensions while Python has libpython. I do not know if such extension exists. This approach doesn't require additional processes to start, but it is total madness.
- Run Python script as a service and instead of `shell_exec()` call some REST API (or whatever). This approach requires additional entities such as services, sockets, but it seem to be architecturally correct.